# Create a table in DB2 using Node-RED using node-red-nodes-cf-sqldb-dashdb

Tags: db2, node-red

Trying to create a table in db2 database using dashDB in.
My query is like this

```
 CREATE TABLE schema1.table1(
 col1 VARCHAR(10),
 col2 VARCHAR(10)
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM
```

But from node-red using the dashDB in module i am not able to create the table.
Getting Authorization Error.

```
The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation
```

When i run the same query in my DB directly. I am able to create the schema and the table.

Comment: This is a issue with the user you are using to connect to the database in the database not having the right permission to create a table, this is nothing to do with Node-RED. I assume when running this directly on the database you are running as an admin user

Comment: Using same user at both the places.

Comment: Database permissions are normally scoped to where the user is connecting from as well as the user authentication